# Jquery loop through regex match

Tags: jquery, regex, loops, greasemonkey

(This is greasemonkey with jquery)

I have a string of data which is retrieved with
`$.post('page.php',function (data) { ... });`
In that data, there are html tags like
`<option value='numeric'>data</option>` along with random, useless information.
I want to be able to loop through each match and get the numeric value and the data between the option tags.
How would I do this? I tried:
`reg = new RegExp(/<option value=\'(.+?)\'>(.+?)<\/option>/);

var result;

while (result = reg.exec(data)) {

GM_log(result);

}`
However, that returns all sorts of failures. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you mean new RegExp("<option value=\'(.+?)\'>(.+?)<\/option>", "g")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('page.php',function (data) { 
   alert($(data).find('option').attr('value')); 
   // returns numeric if there is one element. so use a .each() to get individual ones.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem I can see is that you are passing `RegExp` constructor a literal regex object. This is not a problem as such, but there is no point to using `RegExp` constructor if you can do it using a regex literal.

You can use `RegExp` constructor  like this

```
reg = new RegExp("<option value='(.+?)'>(.+?)<\/option>");
```

or alternatively you can use a regex literal like this

```
reg = /<option value='(.+?)'>(.+?)<\/option>/;
```

Now

```
reg.exec("<option value='numeric'>data</option>")
```

gives

```
["<option value='numeric'>data</option>", "numeric", "data"]
```

Finally parsing html with regular expressions is not a good idea. More on that here [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

try using /g in the pattern Object.

I've tested this with sample code below:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">

           var str="Hello world Hello World Heello you! ";
           //look for "Hello"
           var patt=/Hello/g;
           var resulT
           while(result=patt.exec(str)){
             document.write("Returned value: " +  result); 
             var result=patt.exec(str);
             document.write("<br />Returned value: " +  result); 
           }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```